# What is the meaning of the last phrase in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I found the following sentence in a students' book for learning business English: "*Their shares will yield a decent dividend, **given past form***". The sentence is NOT in a context, it is just an example of using Future. However, I don't understand the meaning of the last phrase - "***given past form***". Could anyone help? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short  "given past form" means in one word **historically**, That is looking back these shares have consistently performed well in producing a relatively good dividend ratio.

Most dictionaries do not explain this well in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-form you will see the term "**form** of value"

It is not simply that "money becomes the general expression of the **form** of value of goods being traded" there is a secondary meaning of "given past per-**form**-ance" similar to that used in ["on form"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-form) similar to the way we use it for sport "His form this season has been brilliant"

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is making a prediction about shares in the future.

Saying "given past form" is meant to qualify that this is not a guess, it is an assumption that is being made because of the way these shares have performed in the past.

"Form," in this sense, seems to mean: the way things are arranged or constructed in a pattern.

I more straightforward way to say this would be to say:

"We assume their shares will yield a decent dividend, because of how they have performed in the past."

Comment: In fact, the sentence is making a prediction but one based on (given) past performance.